# How to use try-catch syntax in Android NDK C++ code?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm a beginner on Android NDK, and less aware of C++. I have written some logic using C++ and then build them to .so file, then use it with JNI for my Android project, but sometimes it will raise crash in .so files.

I want to quickly fix this problem, I want to know if I can use try-catch syntax to my C++ code? (I tried, but it always reports compile error.) If yes, how can I do it?

C++ codes：

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_xxoo_com_xxoo_model_ARDrawModel_draw(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj) {
    try {
        if(controller)
        {
            controller->Update(/*float dt*/);
            controller->DrawGLScene();
        }
    } catch (int a) {
        LOGD("drawModel---exception");

    }
}
```

Compile error：
error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable

Comment: Post code and error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. you can use try catch in c++ NDK code, but it will not catch all native crashes.

And as your error says, you need to explicitly enable exceptions feature while compiling NDK code. To do so add

```
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
```

to Application.mk file.

If you want to catch all possible NDK crashes check out https://github.com/xroche/coffeecatch library.